# Ubuntu 12.04 boots to TTY1

Tags: 12.04, boot, login, tty

Alrighty, I have perused the threads already in existence and am finding none of them seem to have the exact combination of variables I've got going.

I'm working on a computer using Ubuntu 12.04. Currently, it boots straight into tty1

```
Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS [computer name] tty1

[computer name] login:
Password:
```

Login leads to:

```
Last login: Wed Mar 19 13:47:11MDT 2014 on tty1

Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-32generic-pae i686
```

The owner of the computer stated that this issue happened after a recent update, if that gives anyone a hint as to the specific location of the graphics failure.

I'm capable of booting into the GUI utilizing `startx`, but am frankly at a loss of where to go from here. Years of Windows has molded me into a GUI heavy kinda person, so, if possible, work off the assumption that I've no idea what you're talking about and break it down to the simplest of steps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, and you can install the ubuntu again by typing.

```
 Sudo apt-get update
 Sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
 startx
```

And it should work.

EDIT: line 2 should install ubuntu-desktop (with a dash), not ubuntu desktop.

Comment: Sadly, reinstalling Ubuntu hasn't remedied the issue. Also wiped and reinstalled my lightdm and didn't get anywhere with that. (Nor did an install of gdm help, sadly.) I can manually start lightdm from the terminal, thus opening the GUI, so that appears to be working at least. Truth be told, I can't wrap my mind around this--any clue where my problem is?

Answer (score 1):

or try to use this command:

```
startx
```

Comment: _startx_ opens the default desktop environment, but that's only a temporary solution. Whenever I next boot, I'm right back at tty1.

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop  
startx
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `/etc/default/grub` file.  Specifically, you should have this line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

If it says anything else after the equal sign , change it to the line above.  Run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Among other things,  try different greeter like gdm. `sudo apt-get install gdm`

Comment: In fact it would help if you posted the full grub file for us to examine

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/509923/295286

Comment: That helped me!

Answer (score 1):

You could use this command to turn the Xserver back on.

```
sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target
```

Just for future problems.

Answer (score 0):

As well as doing what the other answers have suggested, it could be a config issue pointing you to `TTY1` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F1</kbd> rather than the `X server` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>F7</kbd> at boot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following solutions

- If you have grub installed, you can boot to Ubuntu of an earlier version using the grub menu during boot.
- You can reinstall unity or install another desktop environment such as gnome or Lxde
- This may be a bit weird but you can write a shell script which is invoked whenever user logs in which runs the **startx** command