# What's the default 14.04 /etc/default/grub file contents?

Tags: 14.04, grub2

I, like [this guy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/277736/regenerate-etc-default-grub) also accidentally whacked my `/etc/default/grub` file, though I did it by using `>` instead of `>>` in a configuration script.  The provided answer looks different from what I remember in the 14.04 desktop default `grub` file...what does it contain?

Teaching to fish...is there some resource/method I could use to find the answer myself without having to do a 14.04 reinstall just to find out?

Comment: re-install 14.04 would be too much; it would be easier to re-install grub ;)

Comment: If you make any future modifactions to `/etc/default/grub`, first back it up using something like `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub-backup`. This means if it mucked up in future it is easier to restore - the same can go for most config files in `/etc` and elsewhere.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is still an answer possible to the part of the question "*Teaching to fish...*":

> ... could use to find the answer myself without having to do a 14.04 reinstall just to find out?

I did a search for `/etc/default/grub` on http://packages.ubuntu.com/#search_contents:

> Sorry, your search gave no results

Stripped the first `/etc`, so the second source package name search is for `/default/grub`. The results give a hit:

> `/usr/share/grub/default/grub`    [`grub2-common`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/amd64/grub2-common/filelist)

Do I have this file still on my Ubuntu machine?

```
$ sudo ls /usr/share/grub/default/grub
/usr/share/grub/default/grub
```

or, for example:

```
$ sudo [ -f /usr/share/grub/default/grub ] && echo Found || echo Not\ found
Found
```

As a matter of fact, it is there.

And what are its contents?

```
$ sudo cat /usr/share/grub/default/grub
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

As you might have spotted there is one more obvious different line compared to the output from [Rinzwind's answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509923/whats-the-default-14-04-etc-default-grub-file-contents#answer-509925):

```
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
```

Answer (score 5):

Here you go:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

The file `/etc/default/grub` belongs to no package, `dpkg -S /etc/default/grub` and `apt-file search /etc/default/grub` will both return nothing. However, `/etc/default/grub` is generated by `grub-pc` when it is not present. Therefore, in order to recover it (or at least a **truly default up-to-date version**), it suffices to reinstall `grub-pc`.

```
g=/etc/default/grub; [ -f $g ]  && mv $g ${g}.bak
apt purge grub-pc
apt install grub-pc
```

If you can't access the system because you are unable to boot. An option is to `chroot` in it. Boot with a USB live distro. Then, mount the system under `/mnt`, rebind special fs, and chroot.

```
mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot
for d in dev proc sys etc/resolv.conf; do mount --rebind /$d /mnt/$d; done
chroot /mnt
```

And follow the previous instructions.