# Can only login using nomodeset method

Tags: nvidia, graphics, nomodeset

I am only able to log in if i via GRUB edit the startup option such that the nomodeset command is input
If i don't do this when logging on the screen flickers and goes blank. I understand it is likely a graphics card issue.

I am running a Nvidia FX 2000 graphics card

Can anyone help with a solution?

Could one might be to permanently set the startup to nomodeset, unsure of the drawbacks to this? 
I see others talk about updating the driver, unsure exactly how to do this?
Also I have come across articles about reducing the refresh rate??

Comment: Please use 1 topic to ask 1 question. Updating driver: see "software&updates", "additional drivers". "reducing refresh rate" is probably done with the nVidia settings program (you get that when using the latest stable driver).

Answer (score 0):

> Could one might be to permanently set the startup to nomodeset, unsure of the drawbacks to this?

Yes, the file `/etc/default/grub` holds the parameters for grub. An example of the file here: [What's the default 14.04 /etc/default/grub file contents?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509923/whats-the-default-14-04-etc-default-grub-file-contents/509925#509925)

If you edit

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

Nomodeset will be active.

---

Open a terminal

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Navigate to that line above to the last ". Press i and type "nomodeset" (w/o the "s). It will add this word to the line. Then press ESC. Type :wq! and it will write and quit vi. After altering issue a

```
sudo update-grub
```

and if no errors you can reboot and see the new parameter active.