# cannot remove linux image with sudo apt autoremove

Tags: package-management, 21.10

I tried

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

*With the following result*

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 10.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

**On accepting**

```
(Reading database ... 236998 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic (5.13.0-21.21) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-21-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub&apos;
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: d#: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
<b>dpkg:</b> error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
<b>dpkg:</b> too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: </b></font>Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I also tried

`sudo apt --fix-missing install`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 10.3 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 236998 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic (5.13.0-21.21) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-21-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: d#: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic package post-removal script subprocess ret
urned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

```
dkms status
```

```
Command 'dkms' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install dkms
```

when I tried to install dkms

```
Fetched 130 MB in 3min 53s (559 kB/s)                                             
(Reading database ... 236998 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic (5.13.0-21.21) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-21-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: d#: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic package post-removal script subprocess ret
urned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

result of `uname -r`

```
5.13.0-22-generic
```

result of `sudo apt -f install`

```
Reading package lists...   Done  
Building dependency tree... Done    
Reading state information... Done   
The following packages will be REMOVED:  
  linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 1 not upgraded.  
3 not fully installed or removed.  
After this operation, 10.3 MB disk space will be freed.  
Do you want to continue? \[Y/n\] y  
(Reading database ... 236998 files and directories currently installed.)  
Removing linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic (5.13.0-21.21) ...  
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:  
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-21-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:  
Sourcing file \`/etc/default/grub'  
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: d#: not found  
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127  
**dpkg:** error processing package linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic (--remove):  
 installed linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic package post-removal script subprocess ret
urned error exit status 1  
**dpkg:** too many errors, stopping  
Errors were encountered while processing:  
 linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic  
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.  
**E:** Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

output of `ls /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep linux`

```
console-setup-linux.conffiles  
console-setup-linux.list  
console-setup-linux.md5sums  
console-setup-linux.postinst  
console-setup-linux.postrm  
console-setup-linux.prerm  
libselinux1:amd64.list  
libselinux1:amd64.md5sums  
libselinux1:amd64.shlibs  
libselinux1:amd64.symbols  
libselinux1:amd64.triggers  
libselinux1:i386.list  
libselinux1:i386.md5sums  
libselinux1:i386.shlibs  
libselinux1:i386.symbols  
libselinux1:i386.triggers  
linux-base.conffiles  
linux-base.list  
linux-base.md5sums  
linux-base.postinst  
linux-base.postrm  
linux-base.templates  
linux-firmware.list  
linux-firmware.md5sums  
linux-firmware.postinst  
linux-generic-hwe-20.04.list  
linux-generic-hwe-20.04.md5sums  
linux-headers-5.13.0-22-generic.list  
linux-headers-5.13.0-22-generic.md5sums  
linux-headers-5.13.0-22-generic.postinst  
linux-headers-5.13.0-22.list  
linux-headers-5.13.0-22.md5sums  
linux-headers-5.13.0-23-generic.list  
linux-headers-5.13.0-23-generic.md5sums  
linux-headers-5.13.0-23-generic.postinst  
linux-headers-5.13.0-23.list  
linux-headers-5.13.0-23.md5sums  
linux-headers-5.13.0-25-generic.list  
linux-headers-5.13.0-25-generic.md5sums  
linux-headers-5.13.0-25-generic.postinst  
linux-headers-5.13.0-25.list  
linux-headers-5.13.0-25.md5sums  
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04.list  
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04.md5sums  
linux-image-5.13.0-20-generic.list  
linux-image-5.13.0-20-generic.postrm  
linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic.list  
linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic.md5sums  
linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic.postinst  
linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic.postrm  
linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic.preinst  
linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic.prerm  
linux-image-5.13.0-21-generic.triggers  
linux-image-5.13.0-22-generic.list  
linux-image-5.13.0-22-generic.md5sums  
linux-image-5.13.0-22-generic.postinst  
linux-image-5.13.0-22-generic.postrm  
linux-image-5.13.0-22-generic.preinst  
linux-image-5.13.0-22-generic.prerm  
linux-image-5.13.0-22-generic.triggers  
linux-image-5.13.0-23-generic.list  
linux-image-5.13.0-23-generic.md5sums  
linux-image-5.13.0-23-generic.postinst  
linux-image-5.13.0-23-generic.postrm  
linux-image-5.13.0-23-generic.preinst  
linux-image-5.13.0-23-generic.prerm  
linux-image-5.13.0-23-generic.triggers  
linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic.list  
linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic.md5sums  
linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic.postinst  
linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic.postrm  
linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic.preinst  
linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic.prerm  
linux-image-5.13.0-25-generic.triggers  
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04.list  
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04.md5sums  
linux-libc-dev:amd64.list  
linux-libc-dev:amd64.md5sums  
linux-modules-5.13.0-20-generic.list  
linux-modules-5.13.0-20-generic.postrm  
linux-modules-5.13.0-21-generic.list  
linux-modules-5.13.0-21-generic.postrm  
linux-modules-5.13.0-22-generic.list  
linux-modules-5.13.0-22-generic.md5sums  
linux-modules-5.13.0-22-generic.postinst  
linux-modules-5.13.0-22-generic.postrm  
linux-modules-5.13.0-23-generic.list  
linux-modules-5.13.0-23-generic.md5sums  
linux-modules-5.13.0-23-generic.postinst  
linux-modules-5.13.0-23-generic.postrm  
linux-modules-5.13.0-25-generic.list  
linux-modules-5.13.0-25-generic.md5sums  
linux-modules-5.13.0-25-generic.postinst  
linux-modules-5.13.0-25-generic.postrm  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-20-generic.list  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-20-generic.postrm  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-21-generic.list  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-21-generic.postrm  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-22-generic.list  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-22-generic.md5sums  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-22-generic.postinst  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-22-generic.postrm  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-23-generic.list  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-23-generic.md5sums  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-23-generic.postinst  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-23-generic.postrm  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic.list  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic.md5sums  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic.postinst  
linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-25-generic.postrm  
linux-sound-base.config  
linux-sound-base.list  
linux-sound-base.md5sums  
linux-sound-base.postinst  
linux-sound-base.postrm  
linux-sound-base.templates  
pptp-linux.conffiles  
pptp-linux.list  
pptp-linux.md5sums  
util-linux.conffiles  
util-linux.list  
util-linux.md5sums  
util-linux.postinst  
util-linux.postrm  
util-linux.preinst  
util-linux.prerm
```

output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu  
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10  
Release:    21.10  
Codename:   impish
```

output of  `cat /etc/default/grub`

```
d# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB\_DEFAULT=0
GRUB\_TIMEOUT\_STYLE=hidden
GRUB\_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB\_DISTRIBUTOR=\`lsb\_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian\`
GRUB\_CMDLINE\_LINUX\_DEFAULT="quiet splash noresume"
GRUB\_CMDLINE\_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB\_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB\_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command \`vbeinfo'
#GRUB\_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB\_DISABLE\_LINUX\_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB\_DISABLE\_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB\_INIT\_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Comment: @Someone thanks for your help . I have included the output of `cat /etc/default/grub` . I regret that I couldn't format it correctly, though. Thanks

Comment: Please change the contents of your grub file to [the contents provided in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/509925/1460940) and run `apt -f install`

Comment: @Someone deleting the 'd' from the first line of /etc/default/grub seems to have solved the issue. I will keep you updated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says:

```
 /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 1: /etc/default/grub: d#: not found
```

Your `/etc/default/grub` file has some invalid characters. The invalid character is `d` at the beginning of the file. Remove that.

```
d# If you change this file.....
```

Make it look like:

```
# If you change this file....
```

After removing, run:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt -f install 
sudo update-grub
```

---

Ideally, your file will contain:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```