# How to remove `linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic` manually in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, 20.04, kernel

How to remove `linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic` manually in ubuntu 20.04?

I am getting errors like this when I try to update, install, remove package.

```
(Reading database ... 211704 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (5.11.0-41.45~20.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.11.0-41-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Script `/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new' contains no commands and will do nothing
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 1
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic (--remove):
 installed linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic package post-removal script subpr
ocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to fix it.

I tried every possibility mentioned below:

> autoremove, purge, remove, dpkg, fix broken etc.
> How to remove it manually?

Note: My computer is working fine without any problem and booting normal. I can use my laptop but the main problem is that I can't install, remove or fix any packages.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It says there are errors in `/etc/default/grub`, thus it's a duplicate to this question: [cannot remove linux image with sudo apt autoremove](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386529/cannot-remove-linux-image-with-sudo-apt-autoremove)

Comment: @ArturMeinild Finally I solved this problem in another way. I find all file name containing `linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic` and deleted it.

Comment: @ArturMeinild I deleted all file containing `linux-image-5.11.0-41-generic` on `/var/lib/dpkg/info` Is everything fine Or I did wrong? please reply!

Comment: Fix your `/etc/default/grub` follow @ArturMeinild link for that.

Comment: @Kheersagarpatel It's generally a bad practice to manually remove files from `/var/lib/dpkg/info`. It's fine for now, but in future it will definitely destroy your system.